# os.system call terminates with -1 exit code

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess

I try to run a java program from my python script using os.system.
The java program receives a file as argument and writes there some data. Then python script reads from this file. Java code is invoked inside a loop, and first few iterations complete successfully. But then I get an error telling me, that a file where java program writes does not exist.

I found that in this case os.system return value is -1. And before the error happens os.system terminates in less than a second, while I expect my java program to run much longer.

I can successfully run the java program with the same arguments from terminal.

Some pseudo code to illustrate the problem:

```
for i in array:
    input_file_name = '/path/to/input/file' + i
    output_file_name = '/path/to/output/file' + i
    writeSthToFile(input_file_name)
    os.system('java -Xmx512m SomeClass ' + input_file_name + ' ' + output_file_name)
    readFromFile(output_file_name)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact, you can run it from command line is one thing, but are you sure what status code it returns? In other words, your program in Java is exiting with error code -1, this has not much to do with Python itself.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message from the Java program? Does this include the location of the file? Is that the filename you specify as an argument? What is the content of `array`?

Comment: As an aside, this is a fragile way to call an external program. Take a look at the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky, when I run java program manually from the terminal I get 0 return code.

Comment: @HansThen, there is no error message from the java program. It works properly when running from the terminal. In this example array is just a list of numbers. Let's say from 1 to 10. And the program fails on 8'th iteration.

Comment: @chepner, I tried to use subprocess, but then I got memory allocation error. OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Then what do you mean by: "But then I get an error telling me, that a file where java program writes does not exist"?

Comment: print out the command you are going to call by `os.system` and after it crashes, try to run it manually. It is likely to crash for some reason and this is the answer to your question.

Comment: @HansThen, this is the error from python code, while executing method readFromFile(). Java program doesn't create this file so I can't read from it. So I try to find a reason, why java program doesn't create this file when I run it through os.system and does create the file when running it manually from the terminal.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky, that's exactly what I did. It does not crash.

Comment: Could you show us your exact code (it's always more difficult to debug pseudocode) and how you invoke your python program.

Comment: The issue might be as simple as the wrong working directory/classpath. Use `subprocess.check_call(['java', '-Xmx512m', 'SomeClass', input_file_name, output_filename])` to get more informative error message. Are you sure `java` is in PATH for the python process? btw, if the java program may read/write from/to stdin/stdout then you could avoid using the files and write/read to/from subprocess' pipes